Is the Planck Relation linear at high energies?
As the title suggests, I'm wondering if any deviation from $E = h\nu$ has been observed when the wavelength of light approaches the Compton wavelength of the electron, proton, etc.

No, why should it?

You might want to consider the implications of such a proposed effect.  What wavelength would an electron-positron collision produce?  What would happen to quantum theory -- not to mention General Relativity -- if this were to occur?
